# How to assign values to a list in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this list and I'm writing a function to ask the user to add the info:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXTAB 40
#define MAXSTR 25

typedef enum {Prob, Impr, Terr, Jail} Type;

typedef struct {
    int pos;
    char name[MAXSTR+1];
    char owner[MAXSTR+1];
    int price;
    Type info;
} Casella;

struct lista {
    Casella Tab;
    struct lista *node;
};

typedef struct lista Lista;

void printElement (Lista *);
void printTab (Lista *);
Lista * initializeTab (Lista *, int);
Lista * addInfo (Lista*);

int main()
{
    Lista *list = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MAXTAB; i++){
        list = initializeTab(list, i);
    }

    printTab(list);

    return 0;
}

void printElement (Lista *l){

    printf("Position: %d\n", l->Tab.pos);

}

void printTab (Lista *l){

    while(l!=NULL){
        printElement(l);
        l=l->node;
    }

}

Lista * initializeTab (Lista *l, int x){

    Lista *newTab = NULL;

    newTab = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    newTab->Tab.pos = x;
    newTab->node = l;

    return newTab;

}

Lista * addInfo (Lista *l){
    Lista *list = NULL;
    list->Tab.name = (char*)malloc(MAXSTR * sizeof(char));
    return list;
}`
```

In the function "addInfo", I try to allocate memory for the Tab name, but it tells me I can't assign type array char to that. My question is, how do I allocate memory for various list elements? Like I want to allocate memory for the list.name, then list.owner, list.pos etc... and then assign values to them.

Comment: Use pointer, not array, to the variable to be assigned.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 3):

In your structure definition

```
struct {
    int pos;
    char name[MAXSTR+1];   //array
    char owner[MAXSTR+1];  //array
    int price;
    Type info;
} Casella;
```

`name` and `owner` are arrays, and they already have `[MAXSTR+1]` elements each. You don't need to allocate memory using `malloc()`. Just do `strcpy()`.

Also, `pos` being an integer, simply assign the value using `=`. That should suffice.

Where you need to allocated memory is to `list`, which is a pointer. Something like

```
 Lista *list = malloc(sizeof*list);  //and a NULL check later
```

is required in first place.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are non-writeable *lvalues*, to achieve what you want you need to use a pointer instead, change the structure definition to this

```
typedef struct {
    int pos;
    char *name;
    char *owner;
    int price;
    Type info;
} Casella;
```

Also, you `malloc()` and the pointer points to valid *uninitialized* memory so if you try to read from it undefined behavior will happen, try to change the `addInfo()` function to something like this

```
Lista *
addInfo (Lista *lista, const char *const name)
{
    lista->Tab.name = strdup(name);
    return lista;
}
```

Another very important mistake is that you set `list` to `NULL` inside `addInfo()` and then immediately dereference it, that is surely *undefined behavior* and the most likely outcome is that your program will crash.